# how to mpAndroidChart remove one sideBar on the BarChart

Tags: android, android-layout, mpandroidchart

**how to remove `mpAndroidChart` one side Bar on the `BarChart`**
[image: how to mpAndroidChart remove one side Bar on the Bar Chart]

Answer (score 2):

I found it

Add this line

```
rightAxis.setDrawLabels(false);
```

To hide **only the labels.**

For **hiding the whole right axis,** call:

```
rightAxis.setEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 2):

try this.

```
LineChart chart = findViewById(R.id.chart);
chart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
```